# Flagging duplicate values in a column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a df that looks like this:

```
email      is_new   col_n
a@a        1           z 
a@a        1           x      
b@b        1           y
```

I want to update the `is_new` column of the first instance of a email address. new df should look like this:

```
  email      is_new      col_n
    a@a        0           z 
    a@a        1           x      
    b@b        0           y
```

I have tried creating `IF` statement to check the count of email address but not its not working:

```
   1.  if df[df["email"].groupby().unique()> 1] ==True:
        print('ook')

   2. df.loc[df.groupby('email').groupby().unique(), 'is_new']=1
```

Comment: Where is the `is_late` column?

Comment: What is the column name actually supposed to be? is_new? is_late? is_min?

Comment: @coldspeed its is_new, I made edit

Comment: To me, it seems like your desired `is_new` column would be more aptly named `is_not_new`, because you're flagging repeated values as `1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `groupby` and `cumcount`:

```
df['is_new'] = df.groupby('email').cumcount().astype(bool).astype(int)
```

Or,

```
df['is_new'] = df.groupby('email').cumcount().ne(0).astype(int)
```

```
df
  email  is_new col_n
0   a@a       0     z
1   a@a       1     x
2   b@b       0     y
```

---

**Details**
`cumcount` returns an increasing count for each item in a row:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df] * 2, ignore_index=True).sort_values('email')
```

```
df2.groupby('email').cumcount()

0    0
1    1
3    2
4    3
2    0
5    1
dtype: int64
```

This is just a representative example, but the counts can be greater than 1. I convert all counts > 0 to 1 using either of the two alternatives above:

```
df2.groupby('email').cumcount().ne(0).astype(int)
# df2.groupby('email').cumcount().astype(bool).astype(int)

0    0
1    1
3    1
4    1
2    0
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @DanielMesejo I assume anything > 0 should become 1.

Comment: @coldspeed: Really helpful if you could explain how `cumcount` and `ne` worked ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Done.

Comment: @coldspeed: After `cumcount()` `ne(0)` is checking which value is checking which element is not equals to zero and assigning an int value to it..right?

Comment: @coldspeed How can I make your code flexible so that regardless if `is_new` is 0 or 1 the code replaces the first value with the opposite? so if its 0 value gets replaced by 1 and vice versa.

Comment: @RustyShackleford You mean, for your example, you want to know how to get an output of [1, 0, 1] for `is_new`?

Comment: @coldspeed that is correct if `is_new` is `0` in the orginal dataframe.

Comment: @RustyShackleford Does `df['is_new'] = df.groupby('email').cumcount().eq(0).astype(int)` work?

Comment: @coldspeed it only works for 0 not 1. Is there no way to make it flexible where the code picks the opposite of either 0 or 1?

Comment: @RustyShackleford Well, if you want to just invert the result you have, you can do something like `df['is_new'] = (~df['is_new'].astype(bool)).astype(int)` does that work?

Comment: @RustyShackleford Or possibly simpler: `df['is_new'] = 1 - df['is_new']`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, using [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df['is_new'] = df.email.duplicated().astype(int)
#              df.duplicated(subset=['email']).astype(int)
#              
#              ^ second is better if you want to check more than a single column
```

```
  email  is_new col_n
0   a@a       0     z
1   a@a       1     x
2   b@b       0     y
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. How can I make your code flexible so that regardless if `is_new` is 0 or 1 the code replaces the first value with the opposite? so if its 0 value gets replaced by 1 and vice versa.